# Redirecting all traffic to a script

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, mod-rewrite

I am on Centos 6.5 with Apache2 and Perl 5.23. I need to pass all traffic to the single perl script, check this request in a database, and show needed content (have both static and dynamic content).

The problem is I don't know how not to get caught to the infinite loop in mod_rewrite.

F.e. first time I pass a request to a script script sees that the user needs a static content and redirects it to the needed page, but this way the user gets to the .htaccess rules again.

I thought to add some kind of a parameter, but not sured. Need your help!

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you have already tried. And what version of Apache... 2.2, 2.4, etc.?

Comment: I am on Apache/2.2.15

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a "front controller". The usual first step is to make sure that the resource being requested is not a physical file on the filesystem *before* rewriting to your front controller (ie. your Perl script).

For example, using mod_rewrite in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ perl-script.pl [L]
```

This internally rewrites all requests to `perl-script.pl` (in the document root) providing the requested resource does not map to a physical file or a directory (the two `RewriteCond` directives are AND'd by default).

> I am on Apache/2.2.15

However, if you were on Apache 2.2.16+ (so close!) then it's even easier. There is a mod_dir directive specifically for this:

```
FallbackResource /perl-script.pl
```

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Comment: changed `per-script` to `perl-script`, but both might be intentional, so maybe you need to rollback :)